# Solving Laplace equation (polar coordinates) with Dirichlet boundary condition $T(\rho=a,\varphi)=\phi_0 + \phi_1 \cos(\rho \varphi)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-equations

**Problem:** 
Solve Laplace's equation for an infinitely long cylinder with radius $a$ with the Dirichlet boundary condition $T(\rho=a,\varphi)=\phi_0 + \phi_1 \cos(\rho \varphi)$

**My approach:**

1. Problem can be reduced to 2D since it doesn't depend on $z$.
2. Dirichlet boundary condition gives that the general solution should be on the form: $T(\rho,\varphi)= f(\rho) + g(\rho) \cos(\rho \varphi)$ where $f(a) = \phi_0$ and $g(a) = \phi_1$.
3. Laplace equation inside the cylinder: $\Delta T = 0 \implies  \frac{\partial^2 T }{\partial\rho^2} + \frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial T}{\partial \rho} + \frac{1}{\rho^2} \frac{\partial^2 T }{\partial \varphi^2} = 0$
4. Insert the general expression for $T$ and solve the differential equations.

I did manage to solve the easier part:  $f(\rho) = A \log(\rho) + B$ but I couldn't figure out how to get $g(\rho)$, after insertion and separation of the $f(\rho)$-term (since it only depended on $\rho$) I was left with:

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \rho^2}\Big( g(\rho) \cos(\rho \varphi) \Big) 
+ \frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}\Big( g(\rho)  \cos(\rho \varphi) \Big)
- \frac{\rho^2}{\rho^2}\cos(\rho \varphi) g(\rho) = 0$$

(and this is where I'm stuck)

**The answer:** 
From the example I'm working on I already have the answer but would of course like to know how to get there myself. The answer says:

Laplace's equation gives:  $f(\rho) = A \log(\rho) + B, \quad g(\rho) = C \rho^{-m} + D \rho^m$ but we remove the singular terms since we don't have any singular source.

The boundary conditions finally gives us the expression: $T= \phi_0 + \phi_1 (\frac{\rho}{a})^m \cos(\rho \varphi)$